# webjob message poisoning for servicebuss (type queue)

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am trying to handle my message poisoning by it doesn't hit my poison method. I am following [this article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service-mobile%2Ftoc.json#poison) and this is my code:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("emailqueue")] EmailModels.EmailSendModel message, TextWriter log,[SendGrid()] out Mail mail)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
        mail = new Mail(){Subject = message.Title};
        mail.From = new Email("me@gmail.com");
        mail.AddPersonalization(new Personalization()
        {Tos= message.To.Select(t=>new Email (t.Email)).ToList()});
        mail.AddContent(new Content("text/plain", $"The message {message.Body}' was successfully processed."));
    }

    public static void ProcessPoisonMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("emailqueue-poison")] EmailModels.EmailSendModel message, TextWriter logger)
    {
        logger.WriteLine($"start poisoning");
        logger.WriteLine($"Poisoning message for proposal id {message.ProposalId} for list {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message.To)}");
    }
```

The send method gets hit 5 time and fails **(intentionally)** but then the poisoning doesn't get hit and my message ends up in the dead-letter messages without any action :|

**What am I doing wrong?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you quoted is describing Azure Storage Queues, not Service Bus. They are distinct services, and poison message handling is quite different.

Try marking your trigger with

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("emailqueue/$DeadLetterQueue")]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. So how do I poison the messages? I have Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v.1.0.0 installed